# RadDataForm back navigation destroys iOS source binding

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I also posted this as a NativeScript issue, but nobody seems to care up there so far.
I hope somebody might have a workaround for this issue.

RadDataForm does not bind properly on iOS when navigating back to the component with the form. After navigating back, you can change values in the form fields, but these values aren't propagated into the source object.

To Reproduce
Open the playground project: Fill a value on "test" and click "Test" to verify. Then click "Next" to navigate away. Then click "back" and try to update the value on "test", the binding is now gone and "Test" (or anything else) won't update the value of the source variable anymore.

Expected behavior
Source variable should be updated after navigating back to the form and changing values.

Sample project
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vwLAH9&v=3

Issue Nativescript: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1350

Comment: Curiously, your label also doesn't update through its data binding in realtime like it should.

Comment: I guess all the changes are done outside zone, so it does not update in real time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a peek and looks the the native iOS delegate is set to null when the DataForm is unloaded but it's not being set back on loaded event, that stops event the events on the form after back navigation. A simple workaround is setting the delegate on loaded event.

```
onDataFormLoaded(event) {
    const dataForm = event.object;
    if (dataForm._ios && dataForm._nativeDelegate && !dataForm._ios.delegate) {
        dataForm._ios.delegate = dataForm._nativeDelegate;
    }
}
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vwLAH9&v=4)

Comment: Ok, this is weird. It works perfectly in the playground app. When I do this in my own app, the input fields become invisible after going back to the form (or re-opening the form by pressing home and then home twice to re-open) (I can still enter input, I just can't see anything on the screen. They do still work and with the appropriate persisting now). I stripped my code down to equal the playground code and it still hides the fields after setting the delegate.

Comment: If you think it's issue only with local project, please share a Github sample.

Comment: Yeah I get that, which is kind of hard given it's a private project and Git repository is on Azure Devops.

Comment: Once again, the project could be a sample, good enough for reproducing the issue. Need not to be your original project.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it now (I added css line that causes the problem in combination with the delegate setting):
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vwLAH9&v=7

Comment: I experimented some more. So the first time the view is loaded, it uses styling of DataFormEditorCore and ignores PropertyEditor. And after going "back", it uses styling of PropertyEditor and ignores styling of DataFormEditorCore.

Comment: It seem to have various other issues too in iOS when it comes to styling, I would recommend using your own Angular Forms for now.

Comment: Ok I've replaced border-bottom-width: 1; with border-width: 1; 
Apparently this is not supported properly in this combination. For our purpose getting rid of Raddataform is a lot more work, as I do like the picker and list options. And this has the same styling result it seems. Thanks a lot for your help!